# NodeJS doesn't find Socket.IO in Domain/socket.io/

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've just copied the files (index.html and the .js file) from 'https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example' to my webserver (not in the DocumentRoot).

But as soon as I start the program it tries to request data from http://DOMAIN.END/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=XXXXX-X1 and gets a 404-Error

Socket.IO and Express should be properly installed, I think and it display's the html file fine.

Comment: I tested the `chat-example` and it works fine here. Did you change anything in the example?  Does it still run on port `3000` if so are you sure the request is to `http://DOMAIN.END/socket.io/`  and not ` http://DOMAIN.END:3000/socket.io/`? Do you see any error in the command line where you started you node application?

Comment: The `.js` file _contains_ the web server. Are you trying to run this code with Apache?